# How to increase all values at once in Excel (about 15K)

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Lets just say that the values currently are

1
1
1
1
1
3
5
4

I want to add 1 to all the numbers so that the result is
2
2
2
2
2
4
6
5

Comment: No but their already pasted would I have to remove all 15K of them and re paste with the Paste Special

Comment: Ok yeah I'm usually here for sequel questions I didn't know about it's other forums.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118462/discussion-between-gregory-eaton-and-pnuts).

Answer (score 1):

Copy a cell containing your additive (`1`), select the relevant range and Paste Special Add.